# Subset data.table by evaluating multiple columns

Tags: r, max, data.table, subset

How to return 1 row for each unique name by most recent (latest) Type?

DataTable with 6 rows:

```
example <- data.table(c("Bob","May","Sue","Bob","Sue","Bob"), 
                      c("A","A","A","A","B","B"),
              as.Date(c("2010/01/01", "2010/01/01", "2010/01/01", 
                   "2012/01/01", "2012/01/11", "2014/01/01")))
setnames(example,c("Name","Type","Date"))
setkey(example,Name,Date)
```

Should return 5 rows:

```
# 1:  Bob    A 2012-01-01
# 2:  Bob    B 2014-01-01
# 3:  May    A 2010-01-01
# 4:  Sue    A 2010-01-01
# 5:  Sue    B 2012-01-11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already sorted by `Name` and `Date`, you can use `unique` (which calls `unique.data.table`) function on the columns `Name` and `Type`, with `fromLast = TRUE`.

```
require(data.table) ## >= v1.9.3
unique(example, by=c("Name", "Type"), fromLast=TRUE)
#    Name Type       Date
# 1:  Bob    A 2012-01-01
# 2:  Bob    B 2014-01-01
# 3:  May    A 2010-01-01
# 4:  Sue    A 2010-01-01
# 5:  Sue    B 2012-01-11
```

This'll pick the last row for each `Name,Type` group. Hope this helps.

PS: As @mso points out, this needs `1.9.3` because the `fromLast` argument was implemented only in `1.9.3` (available from github).

Comment: First row of answer is coming as: 1:  Bob    A 2010-01-01
 and not as: # 1:  Bob    A 2012-01-01.

Comment: There was me thinking I was going to have to write my own function!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following versions of @Arun answer work:

```
unique(example[rev(order(Name,Date))], by=c("Name", "Type"), fromLast=TRUE)[order(Name,Date)]
   Name Type       Date
1:  Bob    A 2012-01-01
2:  Bob    B 2014-01-01
3:  May    A 2010-01-01
4:  Sue    A 2010-01-01
5:  Sue    B 2012-01-11

unique(example[order(Name, Date, decreasing=T)], by=c("Name","Type"))[order(Name, Date)]
   Name Type       Date
1:  Bob    A 2012-01-01
2:  Bob    B 2014-01-01
3:  May    A 2010-01-01
4:  Sue    A 2010-01-01
5:  Sue    B 2012-01-11
```